# Android ImageDownloader: Adding indeterminate progress bar while downloading image in AsyncTask

Tags: android, caching, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I'm using the ImageDownloader as described by Gilles Debunne in [Multithreading For Performance](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html), and I would like to make a simple extension.

I want to add an indeterminate `ProgressBar` to each of the list items that's not yet been downloaded.  I have it mostly set up now, by calling:

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    // in the AsyncTask preExecute()
progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  // in the AsyncTask postExecute()
```

Specifically, I'm marking the progress bar invisible as soon as the imageView's bitmap is set in the `postExecute()` …  like this:

```
if (this == bitmapDownloaderTask) {
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    progBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

But I've not been able to find the right test for initially making the progress bar visible in the `preExecute()`.  I've tried various combinations of:

```
if (imageView == null)
if (imageView.getDrawingCache() == null)
if (downloadedDrawable == null)
if (downloadedDrawable.getColor() == Color.BLACK)
```

Does anyone have a suggestion for how to make this work?  That is: what's the proper test for this code to determine that a given bitmap is or isn't set?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why would imageView be null in the preExecute, meaning why do you need the test? Ok, in the blog you referenced, it is using a weak reference to the image view. You test for it being null as he does in the onPostExecute:

```
        ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
        if (imageView != null) {
```

The only way this could happen is if the AsyncTask isn't started but the Activity containing the image view has been finished and removed from the screen, which is possible, so it's good to test for it. If it is null, then you should immediately call cancel.

The downloadedDrawable (e.g. bitmap) would not exist in preExecute, as it hasn't been downloaded yet.

Your test for:

```
if (this == bitmapDownloaderTask) {
```

Seems redundant. When would it not be bitmapDownloaderTask?

[EDIT] But why would you need to test for the imageview to show the progress bar? Why not just show it in onPreExecute (if not cancelled) and hide it in onPostExecute?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I didn't quite follow.  Do you have a specific suggestion for the conditions I should use to show the progress bar in the onPreExecute(), and then hide it in the onPostExecute()?